# How to create Dynamic Spring boot RestControllers from properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

## The Context

Hello, I am new to Spring and trying to work with a spring boot application which serves HTTP reqs.

I have several "customer" endpoints that have different URIs.

I want to create the rest controllers dynamically on runtime or during container start-up. I understand that I can make use of @Profile to achieve this but the need is, I need to replace these dynamic URIs with their corresponding static URIs (to sanitize their mappings recorded via wiremock which they use for mocking).

For example -

1. I may get a request as /users/1/ID
2. I need to sanitize this url to this "/users/ID"
3. Each customer has a ton of such URIs
4. Instead of manually editing and manipulating them, can I dynamically create these controllers?

I plan to create a RestController that can read data from the properties file and create the request handlers dynamically.

Format for field in properties file - <regEx_URL>=HTTP_METHOD:STATIC_URL

this should translate into something like -

```
@RequestMapping(path = <regEx_URL>, method = HTTP_METHOD)
private String handler(){
 // do something
 return "working!";
}
```

Can we achieve this?

My idea is if we can configure the Spring MVC context somehow to register these endpoints during container startup, we can serve HTTP requests.

I couldn't really find a solution on the web that suits my usecase. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update the question with the properties file content?

Comment: `/users/1/ID` I understand 1 is dynamic. What is the keyword ID? Is that dynamic? It's little confusing when you say ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the following approach - [Using JavaPoet to create Sping Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76612500/using-javapoet-to-create-sping-beans/76658163#76658163)

I can read and process the properties file in the generator java class and create my rest controllers dynamically during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what is the actual need to have a properties file and to create methods/controllers dynamically.

As far as I understand your question.,
You will be receiving a request in `/users/1/ID`
whenever you receive so, it should be forwarded to `/users/ID`

Why don't you forward?

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/v1/customers")

@PostMapping("/{id}/ID")
public Response..<> customers(@PathVariable(value="id"..) String id){
   customersMain(id)
}

@PostMapping("/ID")
public Response..<> customersMain(@RequestParam(value = "theId") String theId){
   //do changes
}
```

So, always the call comes to `/v1/customers/1/ID`
and internally, it maps to `/v1/customers/ID`

Comment: Thank you for the response @smilyface.

The reason I need a dynamic controller is that each customer has his own URL for "users" endpoint.

So each customer has his own controller. What my idea is, we can remove all these controllers, create new ones created from the data present in the properties file while also sanitizing the URL

Comment: Your actual need is still not clear. If you can update the question in a way with proper examples, chances are high to get more responses / correct answers @SherlockHolmes

Comment: Also let me know why my solution willl not work for you (to understand the actual scenario)

Comment: This is an assignment I got in class. The ask is to create a dynamic controller as I have stated before, additonally, Since there are already lots of legacy controllers present, I do not wish to edit and configure each and every one of them. My idea is to delete the controller package altogether and create "customer" specific ones dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going in a similar manner to what is described here but I will try to show an example.

I am working in a large project with over 1000 endpoints mapped with spring annotations.
I wanted to see if it was possible to populate a custom class implementing ConfigurationProperties with application.yml or application.properties (or another propertySource) supplied data and to then use that mapping to define my endpoints at runtime.

It took some time but this "does" work. I cannot say it is the prettiest code I have written, also, we did not end up using it in the end.

ExampleService.java is simply an @Service style bean with the business logic to retrieve data from somewhere, like a database or rabbitmq or a file or some other sort of storage means. In my example below it simply has a String variable named "name" to explain how the @ConfigurationProperties work.

Define the custom ConfigurationProperties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ExampleConfigurationProperties.PREFIX)
@ConstructorBinding
public class ExampleConfigurationProperties {
    /**
     * Properties prefix.
     */
    public static final String PREFIX = "custom.endpoints";

    private final Set<ExampleService> exampleService;

    public ExampleConfigurationProperties(@Nullable final Set<ExampleService> services) {
        this.exampleService = services;
    }

    public Set<ExampleService> getExampleServices() {
        return exampleService;
    }
}
```

In your application.yml or properties(properties is similar but is written different), you will want something like:

```
custom:
  endpoints:
    services[0]:
      name: SomeName
      # also some other properties in the ExampleService to map
    services[1]:
      name: SomeOtherName
      # also some other properties in the ExampleService to map
```

Configuration class, The important part in the constructor is the

> @Qualifier

, in this application there were 4 beans of type RequestMappingHandlerMapping defined and I needed to specify the one I wanted to wire my endpoints into. I ended up wiring up a List and finding them in debug mode to identify the one I wanted.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExampleConfigurationProperties.class)
public class ExampleSpringConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private final ExampleConfigurationProperties properties;
    public ExampleSpringConfig (
        final ExampleConfigurationProperties properties,
        @Qualifier("requestMappingHandlerMapping") RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
        this.properties = Objects.requireNonNull(properties);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        //there is probably a better way of getting this beanFactory but I have no reason to further research this as we did not end up going this route.
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();
        for (ExampleService svc : properties.getExampleService) {
            // good spot to "wire" in any required dependencies/beans for this "Properties" mapped list of objects
            // svc.setRandomInternalProperty(<someValue>);
            
            // give your new "Properties" initiated object a unique name and make it a bean in the current context
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(svc.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + svc.getName(), svc);
            
            // this will map the controllers methods to the "Properties" mapped name paramenter appended to "Endpoint"
            ExampleControllerRest controller =
                ExampleControllerRest.createController(handlerMapping, "/" + svc.getName() + "Endpoint", svc);

            // once the controller has all of its methods I want exposed mapped, register the controller as a Spring Bean for use elsewhere
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(controller.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + svc.getName(), controller);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Controller class:

```
public class ExampleController {
    private final ExampleService exampleService;

    public ExampleController(final ExampleService exampleService) {
        this.exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    public static ExampleController createController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping, String path, ExampleService exampleService) {
        try (DynamicType.Unloaded<ExampleController> temp = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(ExampleController.class)
                .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder
                        .ofType(RequestMapping.class)
                        .defineArray("value", new String[]{path})
                        .build())
                .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder
                        .ofType(RestController.class)
                        .build())
                .make();
        ) {
            ExampleController controller = temp.load(ExampleController.class.getClassLoader())
                    .getLoaded()
                    .getConstructor(ExampleService.class)
                    .newInstance(baseUnitAssignmentsDTOService);

            RequestMappingInfo.BuilderConfiguration builderConfiguration = new RequestMappingInfo.BuilderConfiguration();
            // this was important to get a response back that replicated what Spring autowiring does with custom 
            // response types, otherwise an error is thrown about an empty response body
            // if you are going to use ResponseEntity for response object type wrapping, this might not be needed
            builderConfiguration.setContentNegotiationManager(handlerMapping.getContentNegotiationManager());

            // the pathMatcher was added to have these endpoints look exactly the same as the ones that Spring autowires, I am not sure if this is needed
            AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = (AntPathMatcher) handlerMapping.getPathMatcher();
            pathMatcher.match(path, path);
            builderConfiguration.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher);

            // handler endpoint mappings, these are all of the endpoints I want defined for each element in the custom "Properties" set of services
            handlerMapping.registerMapping(RequestMappingInfo
                    .paths(path + "/getAll")
                    .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
                    .options(builderConfiguration)
                    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                    .build(), controller, controller.getClass().getMethod("getAll"));
            // I have redacted a bunch of endpoints but the essential part is to define all endpoints similar to the "getAll" above

            handlerMapping.registerMapping(RequestMappingInfo
                    .paths(path + "/insert")
                    .methods(RequestMethod.POST)
                    .options(builderConfiguration)
                    .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                    .build(), controller, controller.getClass().getMethod("insert", PickListOptionDTO.class)); 
                    // just remember to define all method body param types for reflection to find the corret method


            return controller;
        } catch (IOException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
                 NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public List<PickListOptionDTO> getAll() {
        return getService().getAllUsers();
    }

    public PickListOptionDTO insert(@RequestBody PickListOptionDTO dto) {
        return getService().insertUnit(dto);
    }

    public ExampleService getService() {
        return exampleService;
    }
}
```